# Do references to collections cause any trouble with threads?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I have something like the following code:

```
public class MainAppClass : BaseClass
{
    public IList<Token> TokenList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    // This is execute before any thread is created
    public override void OnStart()
    {
        MyDataBaseContext dbcontext = new MyDataBaseContext();
        this.TokenList = dbcontext.GetTokenList();
    }

    // After this the application will create a list of many items to be iterated
    // and will create as many threads as are defined in the configuration (5 at the momment),
    // then it will distribute those items among the threads for parallel processing.
    // The OnProcessItem will be executed for every item and could be running on different threads
    protected override void OnProcessItem(AppItem processingItem)
    {
        string expression = getExpressionFromItem();

        expression = Utils.ReplaceTokens(processingItem, expression, this);
    }
}

public class Utils
{
    public static string ReplaceTokens(AppItem currentProcessingItem, string expression, MainAppClass mainAppClass)
    {
        Regex tokenMatchExpression = new Regex(@"\[[^+~][^$*]+?\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Match tokenMatch = tokenMatchExpression.Match(expression)

        if(tokenMatch.Success == false)
        {
            return expression;
        }

        string tokenName = tokenMatch.Value;

        // This line is my principal suspect of messing in some way with the multiple threads
        Token tokenDefinition = mainAppClass.TokenList.Where(x => x.Name == tokenName).First();

        Regex tokenElementExpression = new Regex(tokenDefintion.Value);
        MyRegexSearchResult evaluationResult = Utils.GetRegexMatches(currentProcessingItem, tokenElementExpression).FirstOrDefault();

        string tokenValue = string.Empty;

        if (evaluationResult != null && evaluationResult.match.Groups.Count > 1)
        {
            tokenValue = evaluationResult.match.Groups[1].Value;
        }

        else if (evaluationResult != null && evaluationResult.match.Groups.Count == 1)
        {
            tokenValue = evaluationResult.match.Groups[0].Value;
        }

        expression = expression.Replace("[" + tokenName + "]", tokenValue);

        return expression;
    }
}
```

The problem I have right now is that for some reason the value of the token replaced in the expression get confused with one from another thread, resulting in an incorrect replacement as it should be a different value, i.e:

- Expression: Hello [Name]
- Expected result for item 1: Hello Nick
- Expected result for item 2: Hello Sally
- Actual result for item 1: Hello Nick
- Actual result for item 2: Hello Nick

The actual result is not always the same, sometimes is the expected one, sometimes both expressions are replaced with the value expected for the item 1, or sometimes both expressions are replaced with the value expected for the item 2.

I'm not able to find what's wrong with the code as I was expecting for all the variables within the static method to be in its own scope for every thread, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Classic. You have a shared resource (TokenList). You need to synchronize it if you access it concurrently. There are some different ways to do so. I'd recommend using a Threadsafe Datastructure (ConcurrentXYZ).

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx And https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/

Comment: You are right, TokenList is a shared resource, but is only used for reading. It is loaded in to memory at the start of the application, before any threading is happening, and is never altered in any way. It only contains the configuration for all the tokes that are defined. So tome at least is not the classic scenario.

Comment: The code you've provided is omitting some key pieces. For example, where does the `currentProcessingItem` parameter come from?

Comment: Probably the issue is somewhere not in the provided code. Accessing `TokenList` from multiple threads seems fine because it's only reading, never writing. Won't hurt to make it IReadOnlyCollection and make setter private though (just to prevent its modification from outside in future).

Comment: Yes, sorry @StriplingWarrior I forget to pass the currentProcessingItem in the sample code. I do not elaborate in the items I'm processing because I don't think is relevant, those are just BO obtained from a web service that are iterated and processed by the application in multiple threads, I'm amending the code in my example

Comment: OK, in the end It was a classic scenario, and was totally my bad: I was modifying the shared object inside the static method thus causing a complete mess in the threads. (I was not able to find this yesterday because the code is much more complex, and code viewing fatigue...)

So now the thing is that I'm not sure how to close this question... should it be deleted? ... could it be helpful for someone else?... what do you think?

And BTW sorry for wasting your time, and many many thanks for helping me out

Comment: @ManuelNavarro it's better to delete it, because as is it seems to not have any value (problem is not in the code you provided).

Comment: I tried to delete it but the system doesn't allow me. I don't know if it is related to some permissions that I don't have. So if somebody else thinks he can delete please give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, static objects only have one instance throughout the program - creating new threads doesn't create separate instances of those objects.

You've got a couple different ways of dealing with this.

Door #1.  If the threads need to operate on different instances, you'll need to un-static the appropriate places.  Give each thread its own instance of the object you need it to modify.

Door #2.  Thread-safe objects (like mentioned by Fildor.)  I'll admit, I'm a bit less familiar with this door, but it's probably the right approach if you can get it to work (less complexity in code is awesome)

Door #3.  Lock on the object directly.  One option is to, when modifying the global static, to put it inside a lock(myObject) { } .  They're pretty simple and straight-foward (so much simpler than the old C/C++ days), and it'll make it so multiple modifications don't screw the object up.

Door #4.  Padlock the encapsulated class.  Don't allow outside callers to modify the static variable at all.  Instead, they have to call global getters/setters.  Then, have a private object inside the class that serves simply as a lockable object - and have the getters/setters lock that lockable object whenever they're reading/writing it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware that you should take precautions with shared resources an static methods when multiple threads are involved, but in this case the only shared object is used only for reading and is filled only once before any thread is started, and the static method as far as I've found is not accessing anything outside it's scope, so that's why my question was about if referencing a collection from inside the static method may be the problem

Comment: To clarify point 3: do not ever lock on the object itself; this is a poor programming practice which can, in some cases, lead to hard-to-debug deadlocks. Instead, allocate a purpose-built object that is used *only* for locking, assign it to a readonly field, and use it for every access to the protected variable.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `tokenValue` that you're replacing the token with is coming from `evaluationResult`.
2. `evaluationResult` is based on `Utils.GetRegexMatches(currentProcessingItem, tokenElementExpression)`.

You might want to check `GetRegexMatches` to see if it's using any static resources, but my best guess is that it's being passed the same `currentProcessingItem` value in multiple threads.

Look to the code looks like that splits up the `AppItem`s. You may have an "access to modified closure" in there. For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < appItems.Length; i++)
{
    var thread = new Thread(() => {
        // Since the variable `i` is shared across all of the
        // iterations of this loop, `appItems[i]` is going to be
        // based on the value of `i` at the time that this line
        // of code is run, not at the time when the thread is created.
        var appItem = appItems[i];
        ...
    });
    ...
}
```

Comment: mmm, that's a good lead, I'll check for that and let you know... thanks!

Comment: @ManuelNavarro: No problem. Another piece of advice: sprinkle your methods with some log messages to see if the values look the way you think they do at various point in time.